# Expected expression error in C

Tags: c, function

I'm trying to create two functions. The first function accepts integer inputs from the user until they are between 0 and 100. The seconds function display the validation  to the stdOut.
However, it keeps giving me an error saying "Expected expression" when I call the function.

```
#include <stdio.h>
    // function prototype for the function input
    int input(int);
    // function prototype for the function validate
    int validate(int);

    //main function
    int main(void)
    {

        //calling the function input
        input(int x)
        //calling the function validate
        validate(int y)

        return 0;

    }

    // Function definition for input
    int input(int a)
    {
        int r;
        printf("Enter the int value of r\n");
        scanf("%d",&r);
    }

    // Function definition for validate
    int validate(int b)
    {
        int r;

        if(r>= 0 && r<= 100)
            printf("Valid number");
        else
            printf("Invalid");
    }
```

Comment: The way you call function is totally wrong. Instead of telling you what they should be, I think it's better to tell you to go read the book.

Comment: Your functions are also returning no value, and ignoring the input parameters.

Comment: You can't just guess the C syntax. You actually have to understand what every line in your source code means.

Answer (score 10):

There is at least one bug on almost every line of this program.

This is a standard problem for which there is a whole lot of incorrect advice out there (most importantly, only the [`strtol`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strtol.3.html)/[`strtoul`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strtoul.3.html)/[`strtod`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strtod.3.html) family of functions should be used to convert strings to numbers; never use the `atoi` family and [never use `scanf`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19367427/sscanf-skip-any-number-of-given-chars/19367841)) so I am going to give a complete worked example of how to write this program *correctly*, including proper use of comments.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>

long read_number_in_range(const char *prompt, long lo, long hi)
{
    // a signed 64-bit number fits in 21 characters, +1 for '\n', +1 for NUL
    char buf[23], *endp;
    long rv;

    for (;;) {
        puts(prompt);
        if (!fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin)) {
            perror("stdin");
            exit(1);
        }
        errno = 0;
        rv = strtol(buf, &endp, 10);
        if (endp != buf && (*endp == '\0' || *endp == '\n')
            && !errno && rv >= lo && rv <= hi) {
            return rv;
        }
        // if we get here, fgets might not have read the whole line;
        // drain any remainder
        if (!strchr(buf, '\n')) {
          int c;
          do c = getchar();
          while (c != EOF && c != '\n');
        }
        puts("?Redo from start");
   }
}

int main(void)
{
    long val = read_number_in_range("Enter the int value of r", 0, 100);
    // do something with val here
    return 0;
}
```

---

Read on for line-by-line nitpicking of the original program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
```

Correct.

```
// function prototype for the function input
```

Comment redundant with code.

```
int input(int);
```

Function signature incorrect (see comments on body of function).

```
// function prototype for the function validate
```

Comment redundant with code.

```
int validate(int);
```

Function signature incorrect (see comments on body of function).

```
//main function
```

Comment redundant with code.

```
int main(void)
{
```

Correct.

```
    //calling the function input
```

Comment redundant with code.

```
    input(int x)
```

- Variables cannot be declared inside function call expressions.
- Return value of function is ignored.
- Missing semicolon at end of line.

```
    //calling the function validate
```

Comment redundant with code.

```
    validate(int y)
```

- Value returned from `input` should be passed to `validate`, presumably, instead of a new uninitialized variable.
- Variables cannot be declared inside function call expressions.
- Return value of function is ignored.
- Missing semicolon at end of line.

```
    return 0;
}
```

Correct.

```
// Function definition for input
```

Comment redundant with code.

```
int input(int a)
{
```

Parameter `a` is unnecessary.

```
    int r;
```

Correct.

```
    printf("Enter the int value of r\n");
```

Minor: use `puts` when there is nothing to format.

```
    scanf("%d",&r);
```

**[Never use scanf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19367427/sscanf-skip-any-number-of-given-chars/19367841).**

```
}
```

Missing `return r;`.

```
// Function definition for validate
```

Comment redundant with code.

```
int validate(int b)
{
```

Function has no return value, so should be `void validate(int b)`.

```
    int r;
```

Unnecessary variable.

```
    if(r>= 0 && r<= 100)
```

`r` should be `b` on this line.

```
        printf("Valid number");
    else
        printf("Invalid");
```

Minor: again, `puts`.

```
}
```

Correct.

Answer (score 2):

You have some stray `int`s in your calls, they need to go.

The calls should probably be:

```
x = input();
validate(x);
```

You can't pass an integer *to*  a function and expect it to change in the caller's context, that is not how C's pass-by-value semantics work. You should just return the number from `input()` instead, i.e. its prototype should be `int input(void);`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add semicolons at the end of each line of code in your `main()` function, and also remove the type specifier in the function calls. Also, don't forget to declare the variables `x` and `y` somewhere:

```
int main(void)
{
    int x=0;
    int y=0;

    //calling the function input
    input(x);
    //calling the function validate
    validate(y);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I bet the compiler asks you for an expression in some place where you write a function declaration with a missing semicolon.

```
    //calling the function input
    input(int x)
    //calling the function validate
    validate(int y)
```

Neither of these is a function call.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int input(int*);
int validate(int);

int main(void){
    int x;

    input(&x);
    if(validate(x))
        printf("Valid number");
    else
        printf("Invalid");

    return 0;

}

int input(int *r){
    printf("Enter the int value of r\n");
    scanf("%d", r);
    return *r;
}

int validate(int r){
    return r>= 0 && r<= 100;
}
```

Comment: Please do explain 1) What they were doing wrong and 2) How your code improves that. As it is, it will not be very helpful for future readers.